# Visual Studio 2015 Make output

Tags: visual-studio, makefile

Is there any way to get the embedded make in VS2015 to show why it is rebuilding a particular item?

I have a solution with many sub-projects.  When I rebuild I get:

1>------ Build started: Project: ProjX, Configuration: Release Win32 ------

1>  ProjX.vcxproj -> [yadda yadda]\Build\Release\ProjX.dll

========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 33 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

This is repeated each time I build, so something has a screwy time/date stamp, but what?  How can I debug this.  (Yes, it is not a real problem - but just annoying.)

Comment: Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > "MSBuild project build output verbosity" setting.  Detailed or Diagnostic tells you everything you need to know, and more.  Look around some more, this stuff is supposed to be discoverable.  If you don't understand something then press F1.

Comment: Thanks.  F1 didn't lead anywhere useful.  Truthfully, I spent all my time searching project properties but didn't think to look in the options menu.